# ng-select sometime calls (change) = "function($event)" twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am using angular ng-select with grouping to select multiple items. Now sometimes out of the blue when I select the whole group (change) event gets triggered twice. First with the actual select value and second time with the whole event object. What could be the possible reason for it?
HTML code:

```
<ng-select
    [(ngModel)]="_selectedSkills"
    placeholder="{{ 'i18n.common.select-skill' | translate }}"
    bindLabel="name"
    class="multiple-checkbox no-optgroup-padding highlight-first-option skills-select"
    [items]="skills"
    [multiple]="true"
    [closeOnSelect]="false"
    [compareWith]="compareValues"
    bindValue="id"
    groupBy="group"
    [selectableGroup]="true"
    [loading]="isLoading | async"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    [typeahead]="skillFormInput$"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    loadingText="{{ 'i18n.common.loading' | translate }}"
    notFoundText="{{ 'i18n.common.no-results-found' | translate }}"
    [ngClass]="{ 'ng-invalid': !valid }">
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        <div class="ng-select-multiple-value">
            <span>{{ (item.label || item.group) | translate }}</span>
            <i class="icon-wrapper icon-close" (click)="deselectItem(item)"></i>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
        <div class="ng-option-label">
            <input id="optgroup-{{index}}" type="checkbox" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                   [ngModel]="item$.selected" />
            {{ item.group | translate }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
        <div class="ng-option-label">
            <input id="opt-{{index}}"
                   (change)="$event.stopPropagation();"
                   type="checkbox"
                   [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                   [ngModel]="item$.selected"/>
            {{ item.label }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

OnChange function TS:

```
onChange(skills: SkillWithGroup[] | SelectedSkill[]) 
  {
   code.....
     }
```

The skills value sometimes comes as the whole event.